# Can any natural number higher than $2$ be created from two primes $p_i$ and $p_j$ higher than $2$ by a formula $(p_j + p_j)/2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Can any natural number higher than $2$ be created from two primes $p_i$ and $p_j$ higher than $2$ by a formula $\dfrac{p_j + p_j}2$ ?

Acccording to the prime number theorem, the number of primes $p_n$ may be approximated by $\;\dfrac n{\ln(n)}\;$ when the natural number $n$ becomes sufficiently large.

Let us construct an upper triangular matrix of natural numbers in such a way that ordered primes starting from 3 are asigned to rows from top to bottom and to columns from left to right. Elements of the matrix are given by the formula $\;\dfrac{p_i + p_j}2\;$ for the matrix type $m\times n$. The number the non zero elements of the matrix is $\;\dfrac{p_n\left(p_n+1\right)}2\;$ which approaches $\dfrac n{\ln(n)}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{\frac n{\ln(n)}+1}2\;$ for large $n$.

The number of desired natural numbers is no more than $n - 2$ as the numbers $1$ and $2$ are excluded.

Let us construct a limit for $n$ approaching infinity as a ratio of $\dfrac n{\ln(n)}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{\frac n{\ln(n)}+1}2\;$ and $(n - 2)$.
Such a limit equals to infinity.

This result means that there are infinitely many times more elements of the upper triangular matrix then the number of different natural numbers which should be covered by the matrix. Therefore, in my opinion, the answer of the question above should be positive.

[image: The beginning of the upper triangular matrix:]

Comment: I'd recommend adding your matrix to your post. This might make it easier for readers to see how your matrix is constructed. Also, as was pointed out already, this problem is equivalent to the still-open Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: How does your last paragraph differ from the following? - "there are infinitely many times more even numbers than primes: therefore every prime is the sum of two even numbers".

Comment: The same would say that every natural number is the sum of two even natural numbers, since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}2\cdot \frac n2\cdot \frac1n$$ is $+\infty.$

Comment: Also, you have "Let is construct the limit ... of the ratio of X with $n-2,$ " where $X$ has already been divided by $n-2.$ If you divide by $n-2$ again, then the limit is not $+\infty,$ it is, in fact, zero. But I think you duplicated the division by $n-2$ by accident.

Comment: Thomas Andrews: You are right that I duplicated the division by −2 by accident. I have already noticed it and corrected.                                                                          David: No, I am comparing the natural numbers in the upper triangular matrix with general natural numbers.                                                                                 Alann Rosas: I have included the beginning of the upper triangular matrix. You are right that the problem is equivalent to the GC. I just considered interesting to look at it from another side.

Answer (score 9):

This is just [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture), which is a long-standing unsolved problem.

Comment: The GC is talking about partitioning the even natural numbers into two primes. My question is about a construction of natural numbers from two primes. Do all combinations of two primes cover all natural numbers? You are right, the principle is the same.

Comment: In fact, it's not just the principle, the problem is exactly the same.  If you can solve a problem that has been open for over 300 years, well done!  But you should be aware that that is what you are asking.

Comment: @MartinPribyl $n=\frac{p+q}2$ if and only if $2n=p+q.$ Your question and Goldbach are the same.

Answer (score 1):

By the same logic, if we wanted to show that every natural number is the sum of two even natural numbers, you'd be able to argue that, because the even numbers less than or equal to $n$ are approximated by $\frac n2,$ and:

$$\frac{n}{2}\cdot\frac{n-2}2\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac 1n\to +\infty$$ then every natural number is the sum of two even numbers.

Or at least every natural number bigger than some $k$ is the sum of two even numbers,

The thing is that every even number $n$ has $\approx n/4$ pairs of even numbers that add up to $n,$ and every odd number $n$ has zero pairs.

That explains why the "expected" number of solutions goes to $+\infty$ but there are still not solutions for all $n.$

Comment: In my opinion, this example is comparable quantitatively but not qualitatively because the sum of two even natural numbers never constructs an odd natural number.

Comment: @MartinPribyl Well, that is really my point. The limit being infinite doesn't mean anything. We miss half the natural numbers. There is no reason to suspect that, from the limit of the densities alone, that we hit all numbers. The argument you've given doesn't prove that some $n$ can't be "missed." Yes, in this case, we can see *why* we miss a lot of numbers, but the point is, the limit alone doesn't give you that all numbers can be reached.

Comment: @MartinPribyl Another example is the sum of three squares. There are about $n^{3/2}/6$ trios of perfect squares, which, divided by $n,$ has a limit of $+\infty,$ but not all natural numbers are the sum of three squares.  We again miss an infinite set of numbers. While a suitable number of pairs might be a good reason to **expect** the theorem is true, along with the numerical evidence, it is not proof.

Comment: A harder example: Every natural number is the sum of $9$ non-negative perfect cubes. But $4$ would be enough with your reasoning. (It is conjectured $4$ is enough if you allow negative cubes, too, but not proven. $5$ cubes is known to be enough if you allow negative cubes.)

Comment: Another way to write you argument is to treat the fact that the numbers $k$ with $n\leq k<2n$ being prime as a random event. Then the expected number of pairs of primes $p<q$ with $p+q=2n$ is $$\sum_{p\leq n} \frac1{\ln(2n-p)}$$ which is bounded above and below as $\frac{n}{\log^2 n}$ and $\frac{n}{\log n\log(2n)}.$ So your argument gives a heuristic argument for why, as $n$ gets larger we expect not just one pair but many pairs. But (1) being prime isn't a random variable, and (2) it doesn't mean that there can't be some reason we don't know why $n=2^{2^{100}}$ doesn't just accidentally miss.

Comment: If we replace primes in the upper triangular matrix by even natural numbers and use the same formula as we did with primes, we will construct all natural numbers greater than 1 already in the first row of the matrix. Thus we do not need to use any limit to support the statement in that case.

Comment: Wait,ou will never produce all natural numbers via the even numbers. What are you trying to say?

Comment: You still haven't said how we can't get twice the number of expected pairs $p+q=2(n-1)$ and no pairs $p+q=2n.$ That is the problem with your argument. You are making a statistical argument about a system that isn't random. There might be some general reason we don't know yet that explains why some numbers $n$ don't work, or there might just be a statistical fluke. The fluke possibility seems very low, if we treat the system as a random system, but it is not zero. For any $n$ the probability that there is no pair $p,q$ of primes is less than $$e^{-n/\log n}.$$

Comment: But the probability is not zero.

Comment: Whoops, the probability of failure for $n$ is closer to $$e^{-\pi(n)/\log n}\approx e^{-n/\log^2n}.$$ It is $\prod_{p\leq n} (1-q_{2n-p}),$ where $q_{2n-p}$ is the probability that $2n-p$ is prime, is in the range of $1/\log n$ and $1/\log(2n).$ So the upper bound is $$\left(1-\frac1{\log n}\right)^{\pi(n)}<e^{-\pi(n)/\log n}.$$

Comment: (2+2)/2=2, (4+2)/2=3, (6+2)/2=4, (8+2)/2=5, ...

Comment: @MartinPribyl Sure, but that half sum is not the problem I am solving, I am solving the fact that every natural number is the sum of two even numbers. I said nothing about dividing by $2.$ Your same argument gives that every natural number is the sum of two even numbers.

Comment: Then it is clear that your statement is not true. The odd natural numbers are not sums of any two even natural numbers. On the oher hand, the natural numbers are the sums of prime natural numbers. There is no qualitative obstacle such as for even natural numbers. The question is whether all combinations of two primes are robust enough to cover all prime gaps. If we rotate the upper triangular matrix by -pi/4, we can see repeating natural numbers in the new broadening rows with increasing n, which seems promising.